# Django how to use model DecimalField with additional character values?

Tags: django, django-models

I have an input box that must accept the following parameters:

- Empty Value ('')
- ZERO (0)
- Fail value ('x')

I know that I can create a custom "fail" BooleanField that gets set to True if "x" is typed. However, I would like to know if it is possible add these values inside the DecimalField. Maybe, use CharField with Decimal Validation. However, trying to use it with CharField and Decimal Validation failed. So, I am not sure how else I can achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something with validators like:

```
extended_decimal_field = models.CharField(
    max_length=10,
    validators=[RegexValidator('^\d{8}[.]{1}\d{2}|['X']{1}$')]
)
```

I don't think this is exactly right but might be right track?

Comment: My only concern with using CharField is that, I need to calculate a value based on  decimal fields. Would it be possible to do this when the internal type is a string? For example, would I be able to create a Decimal from CharField? Essentially, I need to query values that are not empty or 'x' and make the calculation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I would go about that